# why python list.remove return different results

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Why does the `break` statement return a differrent result?:

Input 1:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for i in list1:
        list1.remove(i)
        print(i, list1)
        #break
```

Output 1:

```
(1, [2, 3, 4])
(3, [2, 4])
(2, [4])
(4, [])
```

Input 2:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for i in list1:
       list1.remove(i)
       print(i, list1)
       break
```

Output 2:

```
(1, [2, 3, 4])
(2, [3, 4])
(3, [4])
(4, [])
```

Comment: ... Because the second snippet only touches the first element.

Comment: Changing a list while iterating over it is a bad idea in Python. (You can imagine it as a `while index <= len(list1): … index += 1`.)

Comment: Also, you're using the variable `i` for both the outer loop and the inner loop. The outer loop is essentially useless.

Comment: @blhsing The outer loop is still looping and hence repeating the inner loop, so it is not useless. The variable used -- yes, that's useless.